# How can I confirm ownership of shares in a stock?

Tags: fraud

I purchased Rivian pre IPO shares with my stock holding of Starlink pre IPO. The company has since floated in the US. There was a lockout period before I could sell. However my broker (Scott Sorensen from Crown holdings Group Hong Kong) told me he could negotiate a sale at an agreed share price before the lockout.

Thats what we did and now he is asking for 86k USD commision paid up front. I would have thought that would be deducted from the payout. How can I confirm I actually own the shares.? and is this normal practice?

Comment: You are being scammed.

Comment: Without further detail nobody can tell you definitively, but this has all the hallmarks of a scam operation. This sounds like a classic [advanced fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam). Also, a company named Crown Holdings Group is listed on the [Hong Kong Securities and Futures Commission Alert list](https://www.sfc.hk/en/alert-list?search-option=0&alert-list-display-option=0&search=Crown+Holdings&year=-1&month=-1) as a possibly fraudulent organization. Apparently Crown Holdings Group It is not licensed, and is listing a non-valid Hong Kong address.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Convert to Answer?

Comment: @base64 I thought about it, but it doesn't actually answer his question about confirming ownership of stock shares.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant ownership of stock shares can be confirmed with the company transfer agent. Contact details here: https://rivian.com/investors/support

Comment: @littleadv wouldn't that just show a nominee "street name", possibly offshore?